# To prevent possible data loss in windows form c#

Tags: c#, exception

If i click to **Form1.cs** in windows form , i get below exception,

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer , the
>   following errors must be resolved:
>
> Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other
>   instances.(Exception from HRESULT 0x80131401)
>
> Could not find type 'Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms.Form'. Please make sure that
>   the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a
>   part of your development project, make sure that the project has been
>   successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any
>   CPU.

Call Stack :

> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>   fReload)

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: did you try with a brand new simple fresh project? do you get the same error?

Comment: What controls do you have in your form? Native controls only?

Comment: in which case, seems that your visual studio could be corrupted. did you also try with a new ASP.NET project?

Comment: See if this is the problem http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2282372

Comment: It should tell you which line the problem is

Comment: Updated , please check thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem, your 3rd party component:

'Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms.Form'

uninstall it and reinstall it.
one way or another, this component is the culprit

Comment: did you close visual studio completely when you uninstalled it?

Answer (score 0):

From this error: ... for your current platform or Any CPU.

Your project and Gizmox.WebGUI project library probably have been compiled with different platform setting, x86, Any CPU, Mixed Platform or x64.

Whatever it is make sure all projects have the same platform settings. Click Menu: Build > Configuration Manager and set all to the same platform. If Gizmo is already compiled and only as reference then find the platform it was built.

Compile all, close designer and open again.

Comment: There is still no solution :(

Comment: Have you referenced the assembly?
Or maybe compile with the same .Net version. Like platform, set all projects to the same .net version target whether it is .net 3.5, 4, or anything else.

Comment: if i choose .net version 4.0 i program does not start automaticly however if i choose .net version 4.5 program starts itself automaticly(after exception)

Answer (score -1):

Since OP prolly isn't still worrying about this, i will give my fix for all of the googlers.

I mainly got this error after deleting something like this from my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
...}
```

And it would get all mad, because in the  **Form1.Designer.cs**  it would have something like this:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

All it takes to fix this error(at least when i encounter it), is to delete the line from Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: your fix is for a completely different problem